# Angular ngClass: apply class dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, dynamic-class

I am unable to set the class dynamically. Please guide me through. Thanks.

I have a class in SCSS file as below:

```
.form-validation.invalid {
    border: 2px solid red
}
```

My ts file has a variable names `isEmailValid`, when ever this variable is `false` the border should appear else not. My code is as below:

HTML:

```
<input type="email" class="form-validation" [ngClass]="{'invalid': isEmailValid}"
```

TS:

```
//make service call and decide whether email is valid or not
if(value){            //value is the service response
    this.isEmailValid = true;
} else {
    this.isEmailValid = false;
}
```

After the above code the class is not getting applied. Where am I going wrong? please guide.

Comment: Check your css please, you need to put (.) before form-validation (.form-validation.invalid)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] on stackblitz, as we really can't tell what is the issue without a working reproduction of it.

Comment: @MilosKovacevic that was just a typing mistake, i corrected it.

Comment: @trichetriche what if all this is blocked from the working place, same is my case.

Comment: If stackblitz is blocked (which I highly doubt, but let's believe you), you still have JSFiddle, Codepenn github, and plenty others.

Comment: What is default value of `isEmailValid`?

Answer (score 0):

You had forgotten to put `.` in `form-validation` in css. Rest are looking fine.

### css

Change

```
form-validation.invalid {
    border: 2px solid red
}
```

to

```
.form-validation.invalid {
    border: 2px solid red
}
```

### ts

//make service call and decide whether email is valid or not

```
if(value){            //value is the service response
    this.isEmailValid = true;
} else {
    this.isEmailValid = false;
}
```

Working sample is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejvaau

Comment: aaahhhh, that was typing mistake, still does not work

Comment: Your code is loo.king fine - check here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejvaau. Please replicate the same problem in stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

in both cases you are setting value `true`. which is a mistake.

```
if(value){            //value is the service response
    this.isEmailValid = true;
} else {
    this.isEmailValid = true;
}
```